# H1 English text layered over H1 Hebrew text

Tags: html, css

I've been given a designer's requirement to layer two H1 headings in CSS. The "top" layer is English text and the "bottom" layer is its Hebrew equivalent. I've searched StackOverflow and Codepen but am not finding anyone who's posted how to do this. I've played with z-index, but it's not doing anything. I've seen some amazing stuff on Codepen so this seems like it should be child's play. Any clue whether this can be done and how? Here's a clip of the design for reference.

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far to solve that using `z-index`.

Comment: `z-index` must be followed by non-static `position` to work

Comment: First, a quick reminder-- please aim to share what you've tried so far as a [mcve]-- it makes it much easier for the community to provide you meaningful guidance.  Also, one question: Are you sure this is a good idea?  If you're using two text elements, one of which appears to be more "decorative" in nature (as it is very close to the background color, and clearly not the text meant to be read by most), then any screen-reader users will have a difficult time as the navigation will be read in two languages.  Also, highlighting the text might get strange...

Comment: @Justinas, thanks, I had forgotten that z-index was dependent on position to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try someting like this with `position: relative;` :

```css
div {
    width: 120px;
}

.hebrew {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #EAEEF3;
}

.english {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hebrew">קהילה</div>
<div class="english">Community</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.title-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.secondary-title {
  position: absolute;
  color: #EAEEF3;
  top: -50%;
  left: 15px;
  z-index: -1;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-wrapper">
  <h1 class="main-title">Comunity</h1>
  <h1 class="secondary-title">secondary title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted, but it's pretty much exactly what I was looking for. If the downvoter could clarify, it'll help me figure out which of the two solutions is best.

Comment: You can upvote if you think it's useful answer

Comment: it was down-voted because it is a code only answer which is low-quality for SO. The author should knwo the SO guidelines as he is around long enough for that. An answer without explaination are ahrd to udnerstand and as such also ahrd to reproduce. Which causes to be of no value for beginners.

Answer (score -1):

This actually works like that

```
<body>
<div>
  <h1 id="title">Community</h1>
  <p id="shadow">קהילה</p>
</div>
</body>
```

---

```
#title {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 70px;
display: inline;
float: left;
position: relative;
top: 20px;
}
#shadow {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 130px;
opacity: 20%;
color: darkslategray;
display: inline;
position: relative;
letter-spacing: 10px;
right: 350px;
}
```